# associative array like in php in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

in PHP we know to make associative array using this code

```
$variable = array('0001'=>'value1', '0010'=>'value2');
```

and to print all keys and values using this code

```
foreach($variable as $key1 => $val1)
  foreach($val1 as $key2 => $val2)
    echo ("$key2 => $val2 <br />")
```

**and the question is how to perform this in vb.net?**

as i know to make associative array in vb.net using this :

```
Dim var As New Collection
var.Add("value1", "0001")
var.Add("value2", "0010")
```

how about to print value and key in vb.net like foreach in PHP? thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although i'm not familiar with PHP (anymore), i assume that associative arrays are the equivalent of a `HashTable` or the more modern, strongly typed [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

```
Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dict.Add("value1", "0001")
dict.Add("value2", "0010")
```

Normally you would lookup keys:

```
Dim val2 = dict("value2") ' <-- 0010
```

But if you want to enumerate it (less efficient):

```
For Each kv As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dict
    Console.WriteLine("Key:{0} Value:{1}",kv.Key, kv.Value)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim rows As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    rows = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    row.Add("a", 11)
    row.Add("b", 22)
    rows.Add("ab", row)
```